# How do I discover the current rate usage in a Google API?

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm writing a wrapper to Google's Admin SDK.  I'm concerned that one of my clients might exceed the API limits.  How can I accurately know how many requests the client will still have for the day?  Do I need to keep track of this locally somehow?  Or does Google provide this information and I've just yet to discover what that method is?

I am using their dotnet client.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like their reports API could do it. It seems like you could just run it for each day to see that the day's limit is not exceeded. Here is the what their introduction says:

Reports API: Admin Activity Report

The admin activity report returns information on the Admin console activities of all of your account's administrators. Each report uses the basic report endpoint request with report-specific parameters such as an administrator's name or a specific Admin console event. The maximum time period for each report is the last 180 days.

Comment: I don't think that is quite right.  I had noticed that one too.  But, it only enables me to track what has been done.  I'd have to check a bunch of places from that.  I'm wondering if there is a more direct approach.